# Lodash findIndex not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

Why is lodash returning -1 here? It's clearly in there?

```
Ignores = ['load', 'test', 'ok'];
alert(_.findIndex(Ignores, 'ok') );
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's because [findIndex()](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex) takes as parameters an array and a predicate, a function that returns a boolean value based on some condition.

Assuming you are searching for `needle` in `haystack`, you can achieve what you want with normal JavaScript:

```
alert(haystack.indexOf(needle));
```

You can use `_.indexOf` (from @Juhana):

```
alert(_.indexOf(haystack, needle))
```

You can do it with `_.findIndex` too:

```
alert(_.findIndex(haystack, function(x) { return x === needle; }));
```

or:

```
alert(_.findIndex(haystack, _(needle).isEqual));
```

Comment: @yeouuu If you *really* want to use lodash there's [`_.indexOf()`](https://lodash.com/docs#indexOf) which does the same thing as the native method (literally, if the JS engine supports it) and with less overhead than `_.findIndex()`.

Comment: @Juhana Oh, that's nice. I didn't notice that. I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The **loadash _.findIndex** is quite work in different order of the JSON structure.If you would like to get the index of the array object based upon the nested structure.The lodash has provided the same special way to do it.

Let assume if your JSON structure is like below mentioned pattern.
lstMainArray:
[{searhName:'Abc1',searchName:'Abc2'}]

and you would like to search from nested JSNO such as :

**searchObject :
{
  searchField:{
   searchName:'Abc1'
  }
}**

you can make the below syntax to use it.

**_.findIndex(lstMainArray,['searchField.searchName','Abc1']);**